# Trojans, APTs and IP Theft

Tags: information-gathering

If I were a CEO of a company making a revolutionary hi-tech widget and all of my firms profits were generated with this product. I would be very aware (read scared...) that the a foreign entity might put some piece of software on our network which would exfiltrate the product designs, strategy plans and our customer database.

Should I be scared?

And secondly, what would the attackers put on the network - an APT? a trojan? keylogging software?

Comment: `Should I be scared?` No, because being scared won't make it more secure. `And secondly, what would the attackers put on the network` How should we know? Anything that helps...

Comment: Are you asking how likely it would be? Attackers use the tools they need to meet their objectives ...

Comment: How likely that a "revolutionary hi-tech widget" might be a victim of corporate espionage? Likely. What tool would they use? Any tool.

Comment: There are no revolutionary widgets or gadgets. You have been duped. Pharmaceutical companies and military-industrial segments are the targets, not little gadgets that show emoticons.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be scared?

I'm not sure if you should be scared but you should at least be alert. If you have knowledge somebody wants to acquire or if you have a reputation somebody likes to destroy you should be aware of this risk, try to reduce it and have strategies on how to deal with the remaining risk. Such risk management is not only relevant for IT security.

> ... what would the attackers put on the network - an APT? a trojan? keylogging software?

Whatever is needed to achieve the goal and is worth the effort. The attacker has costs too and his goal is that the return to his investments exceeds the investments, e.g. that the acquired information are worth more money than what was needed to acquire the information.

Depending on how good you are protected the attacker might need only simple mass attacks or he might need customized attacks or even zero-day attacks. Or maybe the attacker just bribes or blackmails one of your employees to get access to your network or access to the data.